# serializing doctrine2 entities

Tags: php, serialization, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

I have the following entities: `Event :hasOne: User :hasHone: Group`

I want to render an array (like the `getArrayResult()` method, but with the linked entities, so here what I've done:

```
// build query
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('evt, usr')
    ->from('Application\Model\Event', 'evt')
    ->join('Application\Model\User', 'usr')
    ->where('evt.userId in (:uid)')
    ->setParameter('uid', $usersId);

if (null !== $from) {
    $query->andWhere('TRUNC(evt.litteralDate) > TO_DATE(:from, \'yyyy-mm-dd\')')
        ->setParameter('from', $from);
}

if (null !== $to) {
    $query->andWhere('TRUNC(evt.litteralDate) < TO_DATE(:to, \'yyyy-mm-dd\')')
        ->setParameter('to', $to);
}


$events = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

The problem is that `getArrayResult()` flattent all my selected data so I have users and events on the same level, how can I achieve something like this:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1677,
            "userId": 2,
            "type": "T",
            "date": {
                "date": "2013-03-05 00:00:00",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
            },
            "litteralDate": "05-MAR-13",
            "piquet": true,
            "when": "passe",
            "description": "Jour Travaille",
            "user" : {
                "id" : 2,
                "login" : "myUserName",
                "name" : "MY user name"
            }
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `fetch-join` one entity inside another you need to ask for the main entity and the ones you want to join in your select clause. [Read here on how to fetch-join in dql](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins).

Right now you reference the entity class for `Application\Model\User` in your `join` clause, you should reference the association between the event entity and the user entity instead.

So lets say you are in your repository for your event entity `Application\Model\Event` (for which you use short notation `evt`) and you want to join an entity `Application\Model\User` that is associated to the event entity in a property `user`. Then you need to write the join clause like this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('evt') 
              ->select('evt', 'usr') 
              ->leftJoin('evt.user', 'usr')

              ...other parts of the query

              ->getQuery();

$array = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
```

Since you are in the Repository for the `Application\Model\Event` entity you don't need your `FROM` clause at all (you can skip that), since by default the created `QueryBuilder` will use that entity by default for `$this` repository.

**Another tip:**

I think for extracting your result you should refer to the [`DoctrineObject` hydrator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md).

You can extract objects both by value and by reference. You can read on how to do that [**here**](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#by-value-and-by-reference).

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the "reference" in the join clause, using a new copy of the Entity instead